# Updating like count without the page reloading in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using the acts_as_votable gem and I'm trying to update the like count on the view page without the page reloading.  I've tried many guides and I've gotten as far as the page itself doesn't reload, but all the posts disappear than reappear with an updated count.  I'm trying to stop the posts from doing that.  And the purpose of the remote.request_ip is to be able to up vote without an account creation.

Video Controller

```
def like
  @video.upvote_from current_user
  render layout: false
end

def upvote
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  @ip = request.remote_ip
  was_it_upvoted = Ipaddresstracker.find_by(ipaddress: @ip, videoid: @video.id)
  if was_it_upvoted
    @video.downvote_by User.first
    was_it_upvoted.delete
  else
    Ipaddresstracker.create(:ipaddress => @ip, :videoid => @video.id)
    @video.vote_by voter: User.first, :duplicate => true
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
```

like.js.haml

```
:plain
  $('#like-count').html("#{@article.get_upvotes.size}");
```

_index.html.erb

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <%= link_to like_video_path(x), method: :put, remote: :true, id: "like-count", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        Upvote
        <div> <%= x.get_upvotes.size %> </div>
    <% end %>
<div>
```

Routes

```
resources :videos do#, only: [:index, :show] do
  member do
    put "like", to: "videos#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "videos#downvote"
    put "like" => "videos#like"
    put "unlike" => "videos#unlike"
  end
end
```

Comment: Why is that upvote method in your controller? It looks like validation, which you should do in the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect change done by other users then you have to use action cable or sockets, but if u want to just create post call to like action then u have to add add:

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.js
end
```

Then in respective view file to your action add js code that update the visual effect of your like action. For example:

```
 $('#like-count').html("#{@article.get_upvotes.size}");
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't work but thank you for the suggestion.